# variable declared within a loop maintains value through each iteration of the loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop

I couldn't work out if this is a bug or a feature

```
For i = 0 To 4
    Dim strTest As String
    If i = 0 Then
        strTest = "test value"
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(strTest)
Next
```

I thought that by declaring the string inside the loop, it wouldn't maintain its value but after running this code the console has 5 lines of "test value". If instead i declare strTest like:

```
Dim strTest As String= ""
```

Then the string doesn't maintain its value- which is how i would have expected the function to operate in the first place.

Is this intentional behavior by the compiler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Broken as designed"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx

> Note Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its
>   lifetime is still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block
>   more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its
>   previous value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise
>   to initialize block variables at the beginning of the block.

The "block" here is the body if the FOR loop, and you are entering it one pr. iteration of the loop. And so strTest will retain the value set in the first iteration ("test value") for the next iterations (1, 2, 3, 4).

Comment: If you feel that this is unexpected behavior, I entirely agree, but one can argue that it's an opportunity to micro-optimize for performance. The DIM statement really only allocates memory here, so given a good enough compiler, it's practically free (a no-op). If it implied an initialization, it would cost at least one op pr. iteration.

Answer (score 5):

It's well specified behaviour. From section 10.9 of the [VB 11 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15039):

> Each time a loop body is entered, a fresh copy is made of all local variables declared in that body, initialized to the previous values of the variables. Any reference to a variable within the loop body will use the most recently made copy.

Note that the fact that it's a "fresh copy" is potentially important if any lambda expressions are used which capture the local variable. From later in the same section:

> And when a lambda is created, it remembers whichever copy of a variable was current at the time it was created.

(There's an example which clarifies that.)

Comment: I just noticed the same behavior in c# as well, is this also expected?

Comment: @BradyMoritz: The behaviour of lambda expressions is the same, but the equivalent code of the VB in the question, but in C#, wouldn't compile as `strTest` wouldn't be definitely assigned. If you think you've seen something different, I suggest you ask a new question with a C# [mcve] and then add another comment here linking to it.