# Why does the value type declared in this loop keeps the value from the previous iteration?

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

First time posting a question here. Sorry if the title needs work. :)

Consider the following code (not the original code, but a simplified version):

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    ' just a sample array to loop in parallel.forEach.
    ' the sample parallel loop does not consume for this demonstration.
    Dim things() As String = {"thing1", "thing2"}

    Dim parallelLoopBody = Sub(s As String)
                               For i As Integer = 1 To 10
                                   Dim j As Integer
                                   For k As Integer = 1 To 10
                                       j += (k * i)
                                   Next
                                   Console.WriteLine(j)
                               Next
                           End Sub

    ' when debugging the original code I set max 1 for easier debugging purposes
    Dim po As New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1}

    Parallel.ForEach(things, po, parallelLoopBody)
End Sub

End Module
```

This should produce the following output, as written above:

```
55
165
330
550
825
1155
1540
1980
2475
3025
55
165
330
550
825
1155
1540
1980
2475
3025
```

But when explicitly declaring `j = 0` and running the code

```
55
110
165
220
275
330
385
440
495
550
55
110
165
220
275
330
385
440
495
550
```

When I stepped through the code I realized that the variable `j` was "keeping" the value from the last iteration of the loop.

But I would expect `j` to be 0 each time, because it is a value type and I am declaring it in the loop body.

I was able to get the results I expected by setting `j` to 0 explicitly.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable declared inside a for loop. How do I make this to a compile time error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886465/variable-declared-inside-a-for-loop-how-do-i-make-this-to-a-compile-time-error)

Comment: Bottom line: any variable declared inside a loop ***must*** be explicitly initialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable declared within a loop maintains value through each iteration of the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048795/variable-declared-within-a-loop-maintains-value-through-each-iteration-of-the-lo)